# Display a pictures with a different buttons html css javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my project I have a lot buttons and every one trigger a different picture to show. In JS use IF-ELSE and all work fine in my local PC version but when upload it on server only the first button work, for the others show "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404".
My question is what other method can use instead IF-ELSE

This is a part of JS code (only path name folder are change)

```js
var btnsImg = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-img")
btnsImg.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var val = element.getAttribute("data-value");
    if (val == "h1") {
      document.querySelector(".img-cac").src = "pictures/mainFolder/Folder1/Picture1.JPG";
    } else if (val == "h2") {
      document.querySelector(".img-cac").src = "pictures/mainFolder/Folder1/Picture2.jpg";
    } else if (val == "h3") {
      document.querySelector(".img-cac").src = "pictures/mainFolder/Folder1/Picture3.jpg";
    } else if (val == "c1") {
      document.querySelector(".img-cac").src = "pictures/mainFolder/Folder2/Picture4.jpg";
    } else if (val == "c2") {
      document.querySelector(".img-cac").src = "pictures/mainFolder/Folder2/Picture5.jpg";
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<li class="listCAC">
  <button onclick="prHtml()"><strong>HTML</strong></button>
  <ul class="menu-html">
    <li class="listCAC">
      <button class="btn-img" data-value="h1">Picture1</button>
    </li>
    <li class="listCAC">
      <button class="btn-img" data-value="h2">Picture2</button>
    </li>
    <li class="listCAC">
      <button class="btn-img" data-value="h3">Picture3</button>
```

Comment: I did a snippet for you, I added some missing braces because otherwise it would throw unexpected end of input.

Comment: Well, that is a perfect use case for `switch()`

Comment: I'm not sure how to change the code to use ``` switch() ``` .
Alex - its show the first picture and in one of first version I don't have problem with path. The client use only drag and drop in Cpanel file manager in folder public_html.

Comment: @VeselinGanchev here you can read about how to use switch in js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: @VeselinGanchev, I posted an example in the answers, as comments are not suited for code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the `if ... else if ...` chain with a `switch()` statement:

```js
const btnsImg = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-img')

btnsImg.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const basePath = 'pictures/mainFolder/';
    const val = element.getAttribute('data-value');
    let picSrc = '';
    
    switch(val) {
        case 'h1':
        picSrc = 'Folder1/Picture1.JPG';
        break;
      case 'h2':
        picSrc = 'Folder1/Picture2.JPG';
        break;
      case 'h3':
        picSrc = 'Folder1/Picture3.JPG';
        break;
      case 'c1':
        picSrc = 'Folder2/Picture4.JPG';
        break;
      case 'c2':
        picSrc = 'Folder2/Picture5.JPG';
        break;
      default:
        console.log('An error occurred: check the data-value attributes');
    }
    
    document.querySelector('.img-cac').src = basePath + picSrc;
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I try it with first and second images. In my PC with local server all work perfect, but when upload js file to cpanel the problem stay, only first picture work and for second console show "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" or "GET https://sitename.com/pictures/mainFolder/Folder1/Picture2.jpg 404"

Comment: And are you sure that is the correct path on the server? Does https://sitename.com/pictures/mainFolder/Folder1/Picture2.jpg file actually exist?

Comment: Yes, I check many times path and file names. maybe the path is to long... but I'm sure when check one of the first versions all work fine for that reason use long path. Also in console code work fine, is move to ``` case 'h2' ``` but when load ``` picSrc = 'Folder1/Picture2.JPG' ``` show error 404

Comment: HTTP Status 404 means "not found"; as far as I know, the only reason why you can have that error is the file is not there. Have you tried also to actually type the URL sitename.com/pictures/mainFolder/Folder1/Picture2.jpg into the browser address bar and verify if it loads the image?

Comment: As a side note, it is good practice to keep all files and folders names in lower-case.

Comment: Yes, when type full URL show the second picture, its very strange for me. The path is the same for first and second pictures, only file name is different. I type the same URL who show in console when error is trigger

Comment: I have a little "progression", I change all paths to lower-case and file names with one letter and number ("h1", "c6") and now first 4 buttons works fine, 5 show wrong image and after that all others stop show images... This is on my local PC with switch() function